# Angular 5: Read excel file(xlsx) data and send using service

Tags: angular, filereader, xlsx, angular-services

Angular 2+ - After uploading excel file need to read its data(records present in the file) then want to send it to server via services

Comment: i have implemented the same using sheetjs in Angular js , i think you can implement  a similar approch in angular 2+  using  https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/master/demos/angular2  check out these articles too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385028/filereader-read-file-using-correct-encoding-when-read-as-readasarraybuffer/50715289#50715289  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830268/how-to-make-filereader-work-with-angular2

Comment: @JoelJoseph: Cheers thanks a lot i took your SheetJs Approach its the best you saved me from my Boss.
Is it possible to POST the array data using service to server, pls help me on that also.
I owe you :) :)

Comment: @JoelJoseph: I did it using Angular POST service, one question let me know after using your SheetJs approach will i be able to work with excel data, for example suppose my excel file had column 'Age' and several values, will i be able to apply validations like if(age > 23)..... like these things ??

Comment: you can  do the working with data either on client side before sending the data to the server ( in Angular  ) or in the server side after sending the data to the server.

Comment: @JoelJoseph: okay i can do that now, sending data to server from your SheetJs approach is not working can you tell any link to refer which will work with it

Comment: in the second link i provided the `$scope.fileContent` has the array of data afer reading data from the file , you  can just send it to the server or work with it in the client side just like any  javascript  array. ( in your case TypeScript array i guess )

Comment: @JoelJoseph: You SheetJs approach is working best, any way to send entire excel file  to server. (File i mean entire excel for ex - filename.xlsx of size 2 MB suppose then how to send an entire 2MB file to server) ?

Answer (score 0):

That will cause a "too many requests" or "quota limit exceeded" error unless it has very few records. The best option is to use cloud functions to parse the file from the storage bucket once you have uploaded it by using a trigger. This will require creating a new record in one of your collections once a document is uploaded.

Check this out to get started:

[How to upload image file via HTTP Google Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511848/how-to-upload-image-file-via-http-google-cloud-function)